# what is the best way to assign a value inside a nested hash?

Tags: perl, hash, nested, dereference

My code constructs a hash `%oprAtnNOW` that contains a hash ref,  where both the keys and values inside
`$oprAtnNOW{opt}` are determined at run time.

The sample code below demonstrates that a single command suffices to  **extract** a value from the anonymous hash referenced by `$oprAtnNOW{opt}`.

But **assigning** a value doesn't work like that.
When I try to assign the string `wolf` to the key `Dog`, something very strange happens.
When I use `Dumper` to look at the result, it appears that the value assigned was `'wolf`, with a single quote pasted to the start of the string;
and when I use `print` to look at it, it looks like `SCALAR(something)`.

(The end of my code demonstrates that `'wolf` does not print out as `SCALAR(something)`, so `Dumper` has something else in mind.)

So my sample code contains a workaround:
deference the anonymous inner hash; assign key and value in the now named, temporary hash; clobber the previous `$oprAtnNOW{opt}`
with a reference to the temporary, named hash.

Why does the direct method yield such a strange result?

What is the true content of this `SCALAR` thing?

Is there a way to do this with a single command, without my multi-step workaround?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my %oprAtnNOW; 
${$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog}} = 'wolf'; 
print Dumper {%oprAtnNOW};
print join('', '$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog}==', $oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog}, "\n",);

{
    my %tmp_oprAtnNOW_opt = %{$oprAtnNOW{opt}} if(defined $oprAtnNOW{opt});
    $tmp_oprAtnNOW_opt{Dog} = 'wolf'; # will clobber any previous value for Dog
    $oprAtnNOW{opt} = {%tmp_oprAtnNOW_opt};
}

print Dumper {%oprAtnNOW};
print join('', '$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog}==', $oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog}, "\n",);

my $teststring = join('', "\x27", 'wolf',);
print "teststring==$teststring\n";
```

Comment: `$oprAtnNOW{opt}->{Dog} = 'wolf'` or `$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog} = 'wolf`, or if you insist on using more braces than necessary, `${$oprAtnNOW{opt}}{Dog} = 'wolf'`

Comment: Yeah, you are abusing referencing, you need to read https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref to understand some things. When you see `\'wolf'` from the Dumper, it means you did not create a string, but a reference to a string. Also, not sure how `print Dumper {%oprAtnNOW};`  works for you, that should be `print Dumper(\%oprAtnNOW);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```perl
$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog} = 'wolf';
```

---

`$BLOCK = EXPR;` expects `BLOCK` to return a reference to a scalar.

Thanks to autovivification, one is created for you if needed. In other words,

```perl
${$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog}} = 'wolf';
```

is short for

```perl
${ $oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog} //= \my $anon } = 'wolf';
```

which could also be written as

```perl
my $anon = 'wolf';
$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog} = \$anon;
```

This is not what you want. You don't want to assign a reference to the hash; you want to assign the string `wolf`. To achieve that, you can use

```perl
$oprAtnNOW{opt}{Dog} = 'wolf';
```

This short for

```perl
$oprAtnNOW{opt}->{Dog} = 'wolf';
```

aka

```perl
${ $oprAtnNOW{opt} }{Dog} = 'wolf';
```

The latter is of the form

```perl
$BLOCK{Dog} = 'wolf';
```

which, like `$NAME{Dog}`, is an assignment to a hash element.